# How to get complete HTML content using WatiN properties

Tags: c#, watin

I am using the WatiN tool in my ASP.NET web application. I want the complete HTML content of the IE which I had launched. IE class in WatiN provides a property called "Html", which returns only the body content of the HTML source. What is the way to get the head tag content also along with it?

Here is my source code:

```
IE myIE = new IE();
 myIE.GoTo("http://wsspg.dequecloud.com/worldspace/wsservice/eval/checkCompliance.jsp");
 myIE.TextField(Find.ByName("txtUrl")).TypeText("http://rockycode.com/blog/watin-and-xpath-support/");
 myIE.Button(Find.ByValue("Generate Report")).Click();
 myIE.WaitForComplete();
 var myHtml = myIE.Html;
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't know why, but WatiN doesn't give you direct access to the head or html elements.  But you can still get to them!

```
using (IE myIE = new IE())
{
    myIE.GoTo("http://wsspg.dequecloud.com/worldspace/wsservice/eval/checkCompliance.jsp");
    myIE.TextField(Find.ByName("txtUrl")).TypeText("http://rockycode.com/blog/watin-and-xpath-support/");
    myIE.Button(Find.ByValue("Generate Report")).Click();
    myIE.WaitForComplete();
    string myHtml = myIE.Body.Parent.OuterHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen anything which does exactly what you want, but here's how you'd retrieve the head element:-

```
ElementContainer<Element> head = (ElementContainer<Element>)myIE.Element(Find.By("TagName", "HEAD"));
```