# How to run actions in a fake-browser on the server side?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, automation

I need to simulate a user session (login, click, click, enter data) followed by an html page download on the server side.

What are my options, if any?

Python-requests was my first thought, but it can't run javascript--which is why I need to simulate a fake google-chrome/firefox session on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind working in C#, WatiN (http://watin.org/) sounds like it's the type of tool you're looking for. I've used it to log into websites, navigate, etc.

You can reference this StackOverflow for downloading the HTML source:
[How to get complete html content using WatiN properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805486/how-to-get-complete-html-content-using-watin-properties)